# не могу справиться с программой Minicom а точнее с командой candump

Tags: linux

Написал простейшую программу на Си в линуксе из командной строки . 
Для работы по кану, но столкнулся с проблемой , команда программы Minicom `candump can0`. 
НО эта команда постоянно "слушает" а мне нужно чтобы слушала определенный временной период.

Почитал документацию в принципе можно сделать чтоб слушала определенное время в миллисекундах. Но как это сделать ?? перепробовал все варианты почему-то не вышло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
root@R2CPU:/kononov# candump '100' can0
SIOCGIFINDEX: No such device
```

Comment: Дык, там же написано, что ключ `-t` тип таймстампа задаёт. Конкретно Вам вообще `-T` нужен

Comment: @nobody не понял вашего ответа ,  можно в виде консольной команды. Пожалуйста.

Comment: `candump -T 10050 can0`

Comment: @nobody Спасибо, сработало , а то думал что придется имитировать нажатие клавиш на си в линуксе :3 оформите как ответ чтоб закрыть вопрос .

Comment: Да просто внимательнее надо читать, что программа отвечает :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По правде говоря не так всё явно  в документации. Примеров нет и не явно сделан вызов функции.

```
Usage: candump [options] <CAN interface>+
  (use CTRL-C to terminate candump)

Options: -t <type>   (timestamp: (a)bsolute/(d)elta/(z)ero/(A)bsolute w date)
         -c          (increment color mode level)
         -i          (binary output - may exceed 80 chars/line)
         -a          (enable additional ASCII output)
         -S          (swap byte order in printed CAN data[] - marked with '`' )
         -s <level>  (silent mode - 0: off (default) 1: animation 2: silent)
         -b <can>    (bridge mode - send received frames to <can>)
         -B <can>    (bridge mode - like '-b' with disabled loopback)
         -u <usecs>  (delay bridge forwarding by <usecs> microseconds)
         -l          (log CAN-frames into file. Sets '-s 2' by default)
         -L          (use log file format on stdout)
         -n <count>  (terminate after receiption of <count> CAN frames)
         -r <size>   (set socket receive buffer to <size>)
         -D          (Don't exit if a "detected" can device goes down.
         -d          (monitor dropped CAN frames)
         -e          (dump CAN error frames in human-readable format)
         -x          (print extra message infos, rx/tx brs esi)
         -T <msecs>  (terminate after <msecs> without any reception)

Up to 16 CAN interfaces with optional filter sets can be specified
on the commandline in the form: <ifname>[,filter]*

Comma separated filters can be specified for each given CAN interface:
 <can_id>:<can_mask> (matches when <received_can_id> & mask == can_id & mask)
 <can_id>~<can_mask> (matches when <received_can_id> & mask != can_id & mask)
 #<error_mask>       (set error frame filter, see include/linux/can/error.h)
 [j|J]               (join the given CAN filters - logical AND semantic)

CAN IDs, masks and data content are given and expected in hexadecimal values.
When can_id and can_mask are both 8 digits, they are assumed to be 29 bit EFF.
Without any given filter all data frames are received ('0:0' default filter).

Use interface name 'any' to receive from all CAN interfaces.

Examples:
candump -c -c -ta can0,123:7FF,400:700,#000000FF can2,400~7F0 can3 can8
candump -l any,0~0,#FFFFFFFF    (log only error frames but no(!) data frames)
candump -l any,0:0,#FFFFFFFF    (log error frames and also all data frames)
candump vcan2,92345678:DFFFFFFF (match only for extended CAN ID 12345678)
candump vcan2,123:7FF (matches CAN ID 123 - including EFF and RTR frames)
candump vcan2,123:C00007FF (matches CAN ID 123 - only SFF and non-RTR frames)
```

Помог комментарий @nobody .

```
candump -T 10050 can0
```